# Extracting data from a rectangular distribution of points

Tags: filtering

Let's create a rectnagular distribution of data

```
Clear["Global`*"];

data = Flatten[Table[{i, j, k}, {i, -3, 3, 0.06}, {j, -2, 2, 0.06}, {k, -1, 1, 0.04}], 2];
```

If we plot them we obtain this cube

```
plot = ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.007]}, BoxRatios -> {3, 2, 1}]
```

[image]

Now I want to extract those 3D points $(x,y,z)$ which form the outer shell of the rectangle, with $-3 \leq x \leq 3$, $-2 \leq y \leq 2$, $-1 \leq z \leq 1$. Is there a quick way to choose those points forming the outer shell of the rectangular distribution?

Any suggestions?

Comment: for _this simple case_, you can use `boundarypoints = Select[Not@*FreeQ[-1. | 1.]]@data;`

Comment: @kglr Will this method work also for cases where the 3D distribution forms a solid with unknown shape and limits? if not, then it is not useful.

Comment: It seems to me that you have to formulate your question better. How are the "3D solids" specified? Can you use `ConvexHullMesh`, `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`, or `BoundaryMeshRegion`, etc.? Can you use `ImplicitRegion`?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z re: unknown limits—one could use some application of MinMax on the dataset too generate this. Of course then it is a global min/max and not something like a local one.

Comment: There is nothing random about your points. Your points are on a uniform grid which gives a sharply defined shape. Random points are not on a grid.

Comment: Suppose you had a sphere, are your points inside the sphere on a grid? Or do you expect them at any random positions on the inside?

Comment: This question is very ill-posed. That being said, have you looked at alpha shapes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{a, b, c} = {3., 2., 1.};
table = Table[{i, j, k}, {i, -a, a, 0.5}, {j, -b, b, 0.5}, {k, -c, c,  0.5}];
data = Flatten[table, 2];
```

**1.** [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html)

```
pattern = Alternatives @@ (IdentityMatrix[3] Alternatives @@@ 
        MinMax /@ Transpose[#] /. 0 -> Blank[]) &;

boundarypoints = Cases[pattern[data]]@data;

plot = ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[0.007]], 
   BoxRatios -> {3, 2, 1}, ImageSize -> Medium];
plotb = ListPointPlot3D[boundarypoints, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.01]], 
   BoxRatios -> {3, 2, 1}, ImageSize -> Medium];

Row[{plot, plotb}]
```

[image]

**2.** Restructure `data` using [`GatherBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html), multiply by mask array and delete `0` entries:

```
gathered = GatherBy[data, {#[[1]] &, #[[2]] &}];

mask =ArrayPad[ConstantArray[0, Most[ Dimensions@gathered] - 2], 1, 1];

boundarypoints2 = DeleteCases[Flatten[gathered mask, 2], {(0.) ..}, All];

boundarypoints2 == boundarypoints
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

**3.** Get the non-zero positions in `mask` and use it with [`Extract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html):

```
boundarypoints3 = Extract[gathered, Position[mask, 1, All]];

boundarypoints3 == boundarypoints
```

> ```
>  True
> ```